# Cannot draw 'fillRect' after initial draw on canvas - Angular2+

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

So all I'm trying to do is draw on an HTML Canvas with javascript.

I managed to get the canvas and it's context selected to separate variables and get an initial, plain, red box to draw, but after that I can't seem to draw anything.

TypeScript code:

```js
export class ClassicComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('tennisCanvas') tennisCanvas: ElementRef;
  private canvasCtx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  private canvasWidth: number;
  private canvasHeight: number;

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvasCtx = (this.tennisCanvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d');
    this.canvasWidth = (this.tennisCanvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).width;
    this.canvasHeight = (this.tennisCanvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).height;
    this.canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'black';
    this.canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);

    this.draw();
  }

  private draw() {
    this.canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'white';
    this.canvasCtx.strokeRect(255, 210, 200, 200);
    this.canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'red';
    this.canvasCtx.fillRect(this.canvas.width / 2, 200, 50, 25);
  }
```

HTML:

```html
<canvas id="tennisCanvas" #tennisCanvas>
```

CSS:

```css
#tennisCanvas{
  display: block;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

it's supposed to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fCDi.jpg
but just draws a black square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution of the canvas is its html width and height, not the css width and height. So unless you are setting the width and height on the canvas html element, the internal resolution of the canvas will be 300x150. As both of your rectangles start at a y of at least 200, they are drawn outside the canvas.

You can test this by temporarily adding width="600" height="600" to the canvas html element.

That's only good for a test though, because the image gets distorted by the difference between the css size and the html size, so it's probably best to set the canvas's width and height to its calculated width and height like:

```
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
```

See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7au2mv6f/

Of course, that example only gets the current size of the canvas when you run it. You'll probably need to resize (and redraw) the canvas when the window is resized.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much your explanation makes a lot of sense.
I added two-way binding to the canvas' width and height, then set the width and height to `window.innerWidth * .8`